# Trying to display an image from PHP myadmin

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, blob

I am trying to display an image from my database but it isn't showing on the website. How do i get the image to display through php?

Database set up

[image: Database Setup]

Php code

```
print "    <td><img src='Img.php?id=" . $row["id"] . "' /></td>";
```

Comment: Your should provide full php code where you want to show this image and what you have done till now

Comment: you might need to post the contents from `img.php` as that is where all the magic happens

Comment: What is the code in Img.php and it looks like you are actually uploading the image in the database? See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay

Comment: Saving the image in the database is not recommended try to upload the image to a file in the server and save the image path in the database

Answer (score 1):

1st guess, the `img` column contains a link in which case it will be

`echo "    <td><img src='" . $row["img"] . "' /></td>";`

2nd guess, the `img` column is base64 encoded image in which case it will be

`echo "    <td><img src='data:image/gif;base64," . $row["img"] . "' /></td>";`

I think, that is off the top of my head.(if image is gif, amend accordingly)

3rd guess, some wizardry going on? perhaps img.php is doing the base64 decode for you?

**I would recommend storing the image on disk or S3 or something then storing the path in the DB.**